# Trying to get Google Drive to work with PCL Xamarin Forms application

Tags: google-drive-api, xamarin.forms

I’m using Xamarin Forms to do some cross platform applications and I’d like to offer DropBox and GoogleDrive as places where users can do backups, cross platform data sharing and the like.  I was able to get DropBox working without doing platform specific shenanagins just fine, but Google Drive is really giving me fits.  I have my app setup properly with Google and have tested it with a regular CLI .NET application using their examples that read the JSON file off the drive and create a temporary credentials file – all fine and well but getting that to fly without access to the file system is proving elusive and I can’t find any examples on how to go about it.

I’m currently just using Auth0 as a gateway to allow users to provide creds/access to my app for their account which works dandy, the proper scope items are requested (I’m just using read only file access for testing) – I get an bearer token and refresh token from them – however when trying to actually use that data and just do a simple file listing, I get a 400 bad request error.

I’m sure this must be possible but I can’t find any examples anywhere that deviate from the slightest of using the JSON file downloaded from Google and creating a credentials file – surely you can create an instance of the DriveService object armed with only the bearer token...

Anyway – here’s a chunk of test code I’m trying to get the driveService object configured – if anyone has done this or has suggestions as to what to try here I’d very much appreciate your thoughts.

```
public bool AuthenticationTest(string pBearerToken)
        {
            try
            {
                var oInit = new BaseClientService.Initializer
                {
                    ApplicationName = "MyApp",
                    ApiKey = pBearerToken,
                };

                _googleDrive = new DriveService(oInit);

                FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = _googleDrive.Files.List();
                listRequest.PageSize = 10;
                listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";

//All is well till this call to list the files…     
                IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute().Files;

                foreach (var file in files)
                {
            Debug. WriteLine(file.Name);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                RaiseError(ex);
            }
}
```

Comment: Have you found any answer for this? I am also looking how to achieve.  Please share some code if you find A solution